# Pdf bookmark error in beamer

Tags: beamer, luatex, babel, bookmarks

[image]

Hi. I've compiled a Persian language `beamer` file by both `luapersian` and `persian` `babel` package using LuaLaTex, and in both I've the same problem in pdf bookmark as shown in the figure (some strange characters are shown instead of correct characters).

Comment: Please add some code, which results in this image. As minimal as possible. We can't help you with such little information.

Comment: Maybe `\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}` does the trick.

Comment: @Closers: It is not unclear, see my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Very likely you need option `unicode` for `hyperref`. It can be given the following way:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={unicode}]{beamer}
```

Alternatively (for other classes that load `hyperref` and do not have special options for specifying package options of loaded packages):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\documentclass{beamer}
```

Comment: Thnx friend, works perfect.